# How to get JUnit version

Tags: windows, netbeans, junit

How to know which version of JUnit do I have installed on my PC?

Second question- How do I upgrade it?

Comment: Have you installed/configured JUnit individually? or within in an IDE like netbeans, eclipse etc. Please mention this clearly in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To upgrade to a newer version of JUnit, you just have to [download the new version](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.10%7Cjar) and replace the old version with the new jar. It's as simple as that.

There isn't really a nice way to tell which version of JUnit you're currently using, unless you're using maven or something like that. In general, you can tell between

- JUnit 3: if you're using the junit.framework.* classes
- JUnit 4: if you're using the org.junit.* classes (the tests have @Test annotations on them)

In general, JUnit is backward compatible (JUnit 3 tests can be run under JUnit 4), but JUnit 4 is recommended.

Comment: How about JUnit 5?

Answer (score 17):

This will print the version of jUnit.

```
java -cp <path-to-junit-folder>/junit.jar junit.runner.Version
```

Comment: If and only if that's where the version of jUnit you're using lives. Depending on your project setup, it may well tell you the wrong version number, as the version of jUnit you're actually using may not be the one that lives in this location. I greatly prefer j4y's flexible answer that uses your project to discover and print the version you're actually using.

Answer (score 15):

The version that you are running depends on the classpath of the running application.  It's possible to have multiple versions on the same machine, but if this is in question you can just write a test for it:

```
import junit.runner.Version;

class SomeTests {

    void testJUnitVersion() {
        assertEquals("4.8.2", Version.id());
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if the goal is just to discover the version you're using, a main method with System.out.println(Version.id()) would do.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse shows its runner version on JUnit view when you run your tests

[image: Junit View]

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans in the projects window, expand the test libraries folder of a project that has a test in it. It will say the version in the name of the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

With JUnit 5 you can do something like this:

```java
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine;
import java.util.Iterator;
```

```java
final ServiceLoader<TestEngine> loader = ServiceLoader.load(TestEngine.class);
final Iterator<TestEngine> iterator = loader.iterator();
final TestEngine testEngine = iterator.next();
final String version = testEngine.getVersion().get();
```

Upgrade process depends on your project structure. If it’s a Maven project, you can set the version in your `pom.xml`. If it’s still unclear I recommend creating another question for your specific build environment.